# ASP.Net MVC Application on Windows Server 2008 uses static file handler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, installation, windows-server-2008

I have just installed a ASP.Net Mvc application on a windows server 2008.

When I try to use the application I see that IIS 7 tries to use the static file handler, I therefore get a 403 or 404 error.

How do I get it to use the MVC handler?

**EDIT**

Have also tried asking this question on serverfault. It has a bounty [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/103103/running-a-asp-net-mvc-application-on-windows-server-2008)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Server Manager, select Web Server (IIS) and press 'Add Role Services'. From here, select 'ASP.NET' and press OK to add the other required role services.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same issue.  The solution in my case was to run `aspnet_regiis.exe -i`.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS go to your ApplicationPool Right Click > Advanced Settings > Select "Integrated" for Managed Pipeline Mode